# Can Socket Programming be applied to Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I have a question regarding to Socket with its functions of Sendto and ReceiveFrom be applied to Bluetooth. I understand Socket is technology independent regardless whether s wifi or bluetooth. Is that correct?

Comment: In theory you might be able to transmit UDP packets over bluetooth, but the security model (pairing) would interfere with a true connectionless protocol. Others have tried and failed on Android and Windows, so it doesn't sound promising.

Comment: What do you mean by Socket? Are you using Windows socket (winsock)? If yes, you can use socket programming for bluetooth. More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363059(v=vs.85).aspx